# How to pass route parameter in a href using Alpine.js

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I am using Alpine.js for the first time inside of a Laravel project and would like to add an a href tag to a component however I am unsure how to route the parameter correctly

```
<template x-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="index">
    <a x-bind:href="post.id">
        <p class="mt-2 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 truncate pointer-events-none">
            <span x-text="post.text"></span>
        </p>
    </a>
</template>
```

does redirect to

```
/id
```

and passes the id but I need to go to the named route posts and expect

```
/posts/id
```

if I add

```
 <a x-bind:href="posts/post.id">
```

the result is a redirect with

```
/posts/NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this: `<a x-bind:href="posts + '/' + post.id">`

Comment: I had to add to <a x-bind:href="'posts' + '/' + post.id"> but yes simple js concat is allthat I needed thanks Maik

Comment: @cinameng you welcome ;-)

Comment: I have an additional follow up question to this situation.
If cinamengs <a></a> Tag looked like this:
<div
  @click="getValue(val)"
   x-text="val"
 ></div>

Asuming "geValue(val)" is a function that sets Object-Values that should be used in the route, how should this look to get the routing working.
I have basicly the same situation and don't fully understand how the Laravel/css <>Alpine Value exchange happens here.

Comment: Nevermind i found a solution by using 
window.location.href = "/target_route/";
inside the js object allowing for a script based rerouting.